# Creating new arrays based on unique keys and condition in Python

Tags: python, excel, indexing, match

I'm planning to calculate large amount of data in Python instead of Excel, but I'm stuck since I know the Excel command and I have great difficulties to replicating it in Python.

Essentially, I'd like to import CSV file, identify the location of column C, and then for all unique values in column A, sum all values in C that apply to the condition `1990 < x < 2000` in B

```
A,B,C
9,1952,125
2,1994,69
3,1973,72
5,1992,85
1,1994,38
1,1994,95
4,1992,29
8,1984,94
```

I begin with:

```
import csv
with open('TestCase.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    row1 = next(reader)
```

Instead of writing multiple `if` statements, I'd like to create new arrays, composed from 0 and 1, and then sum all values in C.

Given another condition the result would look like this

```
1980<x<1989 94
1990<x<2000 316
```

Extra bonus would be the total number of unique values in A, that represent the total sum

```
UniqueValues    Condition   TotalSum
1   1980<x<1989 94
4   1990<x<2000 316
```

Comment: What is your output expectation ? I can help you.

Comment: Should unique values filered out?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar Ultimately, I'd like see the total sum of values in C, that apply the condition mentioned for B. Next step would be to add another condition, e.g. 1980<x<1989 and see the total sum for this.

Comment: @ThomasJunk No. The sum must consist all values.

Comment: @energyMax I posted an answer it returns a dictionary. do you need anything else ? tell me I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
l = list()
d = dict()
with open('TestCase.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        l.append(line.rstrip("\n").split(',')) # l=[[9,1952,125],[2,1994,69],...]

    for item in l:
        if 1990 < int(item[1]) < 2000: # The desired condition for colum B 
            d[item[0]] = d[item[0]] + int(item[2]) if item[0] in d else int(item[2])
```

The `d` dictionary will be the unique value of `A` as its key and sum of `C` as its value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, this can be vectorised via `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# filter column B, group by A, sum C
res = df.loc[df['B'].between(1990, 2000)]\
        .groupby('A')['C'].sum()\
        .reset_index()
```

Result:

```
   A    C
0  1  133
1  2   69
2  4   29
3  5   85
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = StringIO("""
A,B,C
9,1952,125
2,1994,69
3,1973,72
5,1992,85
1,1994,38
1,1994,95
4,1992,29
8,1984,94
""")

df = pd.read_csv(txt )

#condition = (df["B"] >1980) & (df["B"] < 1989)
condition = (df["B"] >1990) & (df["B"] < 2000)
df_cond = df[condition]

df_uniq = df_cond.drop_duplicates('A', keep=False)
df_uniq_keep_first = df_cond.drop_duplicates('A', keep="first")
df_uniq_keep_last = df_cond.drop_duplicates('A', keep="last")

sum_dupl = df_cond["C"].sum()
sum_uniq = df_uniq["C"].sum()
sum_uniq_keep_first = df_uniq_keep_first["C"].sum()
sum_uniq_keep_last = df_uniq_keep_last["C"].sum()

print("sum with duplicates  : " + str(sum_dupl))            #316
print("sum pure unique      : " + str(sum_uniq))            #183
print("sum unique keep first: " + str(sum_uniq_keep_first)) #221 
print("sum unique keep last : " + str(sum_uniq_keep_last))  #278
```

Comment: This works, but for the condition 1990<x<2000 returns 221, when it should 316. It doesn't take into account all values

Comment: Thanks. How would this work if I import txt? Should i use import CSV and use the StringIO function on it?

Comment: filename = "file_to_import.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename )

I have used  StringIO just to "convert" text variable into a file for demo code.

i.e. you will not need 
from io import StringIO

Comment: Thanks. It works like charm. What does command 'df_cond.drop_duplicates' do in this case?

Comment: I tried to satisfy your requirement " take into account **all values**" - so no unique. I have just edited the demo code for various ways how to treat duplicates {False, "first", "last"} . As you can see for the condition = (df["B"] >1990) & (df["B"] < 2000) ,  the way how duplicates are treated has  essential consequences.